# Show subterms in a page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have two categories and each one has subcategories. I put the parent categories in a menu. What I need is: when I click a parent category its subcategories should be shown in a new page.

How I should that? I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I'll try to be more typical. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Taxonomy VTN](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_vtn) provide new pages for taxonomy terms, as described in its page it provide what you want by `Terms of a parent: taxonomy_vtn/voc/xxx/xxx` option

in Drupal 7 you can use views to show child terms in page when you click on parent term:

1. create new views for `taxonomy terms` (you should select `taxonomy terms` in creation form)
2. create page display
3. select `taxonomy/term/%` as path
4. use `argument`

Comment: This module is only for drupal 6

Comment: so I think its better to write small module, like I write here: http://7seeb.ir/fa/apple/1/article/all/all

Comment: Do you have any example of the code? Such functionality should be already exist i guess

Comment: answer updated, if you try anything lets talk about your code

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7 you don't have arguments, but you have Contextual filters and Relationships. I have managed to use those to get parent term but not child terms.